# fullcalendar angular - updating database on eventDrop and eventResize

Tags: angular, callback, scope, fullcalendar

I have setup fullcalendar in an angular project, and have successfully pulled data from my api to populate the events:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-installboard',
  templateUrl: './installboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./installboard.component.scss']
})
export class InstallboardComponent implements OnInit {

  appointments: any = [];

  constructor(private appointmentService: AppointmentService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pullAppointments();
  }

  public pullAppointments() {
    this.appointmentService.getInstallBoardAppointments().subscribe(data => {
      // logic for processing data into events array //
      this.renderCalendar();
    });
  }
```

Where I run into trouble is here. I have eventDrop and eventResize added to the calendar but I am very confused with the scopes of their callback functions? I would like to be able to make a call to my service and pass parameters in to create an api call back to the database and save the updates.

I have tried making calls to the service, as well as to public functions within the component but all throw typescript errors saying the functions don't exist.

```
  public renderCalendar() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin, bootstrapPlugin],
      editable: true,
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
      header: { center: 'dayGridMonth, timeGridWeek, list' },
      timeZone: 'UTC',
      businessHours: {
        daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        startTime: '08:30',
        endTime: '17:00'
      },
      slotDuration: '00:15:00',
      slotLabelInterval: '01:00',
      scrollTime: '08:00:00',
      hiddenDays: [0],
      eventSources: this.appointments,
      eventDrop: function(info) {
        console.log(info.event.id);
        console.log(info.event.start);
        console.log(info.event.end);
        this.appointmentService.updateInstallBoardAppointments(info);
      },
      eventResize: function(info) {
        alert('it changed');
      }
    });

    calendar.render();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there may be a self referance problem. try this

```
public renderCalendar() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var self=this;
    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin, bootstrapPlugin],
      editable: true,
      themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
      header: { center: 'dayGridMonth, timeGridWeek, list' },
      timeZone: 'UTC',
      businessHours: {
        daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        startTime: '08:30',
        endTime: '17:00'
      },
      slotDuration: '00:15:00',
      slotLabelInterval: '01:00',
      scrollTime: '08:00:00',
      hiddenDays: [0],
      eventSources: this.appointments,
      eventDrop: function(info) {
        console.log(info.event.id);
        console.log(info.event.start);
        console.log(info.event.end);
        self.appointmentService.updateInstallBoardAppointments(info);
      },
      eventResize: function(info) {
        alert('it changed');
      }
    });

    calendar.render();
 }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Any clarification, resources to read through, that can elaborate on why 'this' doesn't work? And what var self=this & self.function are accomplishing to resolve the self reference issue?

Comment: in that function this related to evenDrop. then there is no appointmentService in eventDrop event so it says undefined we changed general this of component to self so solved mixing of them.